# Wsgen is not generating

Tags: java, web-services, soap

What is the problem with my command?

when I am writing this

```
wsgen -keep -verbose -cp . com.myyong.ws.ServerInfo
```

It gives error

> Class not found: "com.mkyong.ws.ServerInfo"

And when I write this. Removing "." after "-cp"

```
wsgen -keep -verbose -cp  com.myyong.ws.ServerInfo
```

It gives

> Missing SEI

Secondly what is "." here?

```
wsgen -keep -verbose -cp . com.myyong.ws.ServerInfo
```

I am following [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/)

Comment: I am in the project folder path ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for wsgen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/wsgen.html) states:

> **-cp** ***path***
>   The location of the input class files.

So, the `-cp` option must be followed by whitespace, followed by a directory where your source package is located.

In most operating systems, including Windows, Linux, and OS X, the period (`.`) refers to the current directory.

If you specify `-cp .`, there must exist a directory named "com" under the current directory.  More than that, there must be a file named `com/myyong/ws/ServerInfo.class` relative to the current directory.

wsgen always interprets the argument which follows `-cp` as a classpath.  So if you omit the `.` argument, the next argument is interpreted as a classpath, and since there are no more arguments, the required SEI (service endpoint interface class) appears to be missing.